# Set StringFormat in xaml Style returns binding error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to create a style for textboxes containing numeric values, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MoneyTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5,10,5" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=., StringFormat='#,##0.00;-#,##0.00'}" />
</Style>
```

I use the style like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbNumerical" Text="{Binding Receipt.Amount}" Style="{StaticResource MoneyTextbox}" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

But the returns the following error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to
>   perform 'two-way' conversions between types
>   'ViewModel.UserControl.vmReceipt' and 'System.String'. Consider using
>   Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=.;
>   DataItem=vmReceipt' (HashCode=48860040); target element is 'TextBox'
>   (Name=tbNumerical); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style defines the default value of 'Text'. But through

```
Text="{Binding Receipt.Amount}"
```

you override the value of 'Text' defined by your style.

You have to redefine the whole value of 'Text'

```
Text="{Binding Path=Receipt.Amount, StringFormat='#,##0.00;-#,##0.00'}"
```

The problem is that 'StringFormat' is a property of the binding and not of the 'Text' attribute.